# Regular expression where first letter in a word is uppercase, and word is surrounded by _

Tags: python, regex

Basically I wont regular expression that will accept only this:

```
Dog  
Cat_Dog   
Cat_Dog_Mouse
```

Numbers are allowed. [0-9] And are treated as words

```
Dog_003  -> OK  
Dog003   -> NOT OK  
Dog_003_ -> NOT OK
```

This is not allowed:

```
DoG  
DOg  
DOG (only first letter is uppercase)
Cat_Dog_
_Cat_Dog_ (_ can be only between words)
```

It will be used in Python.

**My solution**

```
reTitle2 = re.compile(
            """
             ^([A-Z]{1}|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*|[0-9]+)         # first part 
              (_[A-Z]{1}|_[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*|_[0-9]+)*     # zero or more times 
              ([A-Z]{1}|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*|[0-9]+){0,1}$   # last part
            """
            , re.UNICODE | re.VERBOSE)
```

There are some redundant parts, but I make it more easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution**

```
reTitle2 = re.compile(
            """
             ^([A-Z]{1}|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*|[0-9]+)         # first part 
              (_[A-Z]{1}|_[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*|_[0-9]+)*     # zero or more times 
              ([A-Z]{1}|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*|[0-9]+){0,1}$   # last part
            """
            , re.UNICODE | re.VERBOSE)
```

There are some redundant parts, but I make it more easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

The regex is:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*(_([A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+))*
```

or, if `003_Dog` is allowed:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+)(_([A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+))*
```

Comment: Your regex is NOT good (eg. it accept DOG) but I gave me some ideas. I have posted my idea.

Comment: It's just missing anchors.